# How to change toRecipients color for MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using MFMailComposeViewController in my app. I wanna change the color of toRecipients

my code:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailPicker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject: info.mail];
[mailPicker setToRecipients: toRecipients];
```

Is it possible to change the color of toRecipients ? If it is possible, how can I do this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: y do u want to change the color of toRecipients?

Comment: There is no special reason ，just i think a red color is good for my app, and my navigationbar is also red .

Comment: go to storyboard file and select File Inspector and there change global tint to red color. hope it helps